# SetExpressCheckout token received but Sandbox claims transaction has expired

Tags: c#, api, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've been attempting to process a very simple express checkout Sandbox transaction using the C# Paypal API, but keep getting a session timeout error on the Paypal website after the redirect.

I should emphasize that I get a successful ACK response from SetExpressCheckout along with a Token string.

Here is an example of the checkout URL I've been trying to redirect to:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-9RY2628262462061J

My return address is localhost, but I couldn't see anywhere that this would be a problem in Sandbox.

On trying to redirect to the Sandbox I arrive not at the checkout URL but at this address:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=CzvBHQErPEHw5gOt51FV88G_4L9HUCLypeGkwVZLW6mkWsZOofIpFR2K6Aa&dispatch=50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b081984719ecfa9a8ffe80733a1a700ced90ae

And see the following error message:

"This transaction has expired. Please return to the recipient's website to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow."

How can the transaction be timing out when [1] I have a successful API response along with a token and [2] I literally redirect there immediately after getting the token.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

If it helps here is the C# I wrote to access the API. As noted, I get a success ACK response plus a token.

```
try
        {
            var details = ToPaymentDetails(data);

            var request = new SetExpressCheckoutReq();
            request.SetExpressCheckoutRequest = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType
            {
                SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = details,
                Version = Version
            };
            var result = await client.SetExpressCheckoutAsync(credentials, request);
            var response = result.SetExpressCheckoutResponse1;

            FailOnError(response);

            return Result.Success(response.Token);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Result.Error<string>("Received an error from Paypal.SetExpressCheckout.", exception: ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The EC token only last for 3 hours. You will have to recall the SetEC API to get a new EC token and proceed with the checkout flow.

Comment: As mentioned above, though, after calling SetExpressCheckout and getting the token I redirect the user to Paypal immediately. Do you know why I would be getting that session timeout error in that circumstance?

Answer (score 0):

I am not closer to understanding why the SOAP API call generates a token that is rejected by Paypal, but I found that I was able to reach the Sandbox payment page if I used the SDK to generate a payment.

This hasn't exactly been an enlightening or educational experience ...